# Cryptocurrency with support for a shared wallet

Tags: currencies

Consider a scenario where 5 cryptocurrency holders wish to create a partnership. All of them add an amount of money into a wallet to finance an idea. The wallet is shared between all of the partners to view and deposit into, but in order to withdraw, all 5 (or possibly the majority 4/5) must view the proposed transaction give some sort of permission. 
Is there a cryptocurrency which could fit the above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a cryptocurrency which could fit the above scenario?

yes, bitcoin: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Multisignature

Comment: I have no idea how i missed that...